# /dev/fd/63: Permission denied when trying to make_config.sh for OpenVPN

Tags: server, permissions, vpn, openvpn

I followed the article here:
[How To Set Up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 18.04 | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04)

And when running `~/client-configs/make_config.sh` I received this error:

```
./make_config.sh: line 9: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
/root/openvpn-ca/keys/ca.crt: line 1: -----BEGIN: command not found
/root/openvpn-ca/keys/ca.crt: line 2: etc etc.... (certificate file)
/root/openvpn-ca/keys/ca.crt: line 30: -----END: command not found
./make_config.sh: line 12: /root/openvpn-ca/keys/server.crt: No such file or directory
./make_config.sh: line 14: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./make_config.sh: line 15: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
/root/openvpn-ca/keys/ta.key: line 4: -----BEGIN: command not found
/root/openvpn-ca/keys/ta.key: line 5: etc. etc... (certificate file)
/root/openvpn-ca/keys/ta.key: line 21: -----END: command not found
./make_config.sh: line 17: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

This is the `make_config.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First argument: Client identifier                                                                                                                      
KEY_DIR=~/openvpn-ca/keys
OUTPUT_DIR=~/client-configs/files
BASE_CONFIG=~/client-configs/base.conf

cat ${BASE_CONFIG} \
        <(echo -e '<ca>') \
        ${KEY_DIR}/ca.crt \
        <(echo -e '</ca>\n<cert>') \
        ${KEY_DIR}/${1}.crt \
        <(echo -e '</cert>\n<key>') \
        ${KEY_DIR}/${1}.key \
        <(echo -e '</key>\n<tls-auth>') \
        ${KEY_DIR}/ta.key \
        <(echo -e '</tls-auth>') \
        > ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${1}.ovpn
```

Not sure what to do to fix it at this point.

Comment: The instructions you liked say to run `sudo ./make_config.sh client1` - are you actually doing so, or did you switch to `root`? Is your system actually 18.04, or is it a newer version (where `sudo` may have been configured to `always_set_home`)?

Comment: @steeldriver I've tried it with either and both of them fail. System is indeed v18.04

Comment: What the error messages suggest is that there is something malformed about your multi-line `cat` command (perhaps whitespace or control characters after the backslashes?) that is causing the shell to try to execute the lines rather than passing them as arguments to `cat`

Comment: @steeldriver PERFECT! Turns out there were extra spaces after the slashes. Removing those immediately worked. Thank you.